# Properly using props between components using React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json

My goal is to use data from a json file to pass certain information using the concept of props in react in order to load multiple images (cards).

I am using three components to complete this project, App, MainCard, and the json file called Data.

I am having difficulty getting the image to load.

here is the json file

```
{
"HipHop": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "url":"../public/MainCardImages/hiphopMainCard.png",
    "description": "HipHopCard",
    "title": "Hip Hop"
  }
],
"House":[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "url":"../public/MainCardImages/houseMainCard.png",
    "description": "House Card",
    "title": "House"
  }
]
```

}

here is app.jsx

```
import MainCard from './components/MainCard'
import Data from "./data.json"

function App() {
  const maincard = Data.map(card => {
    return(
      <MainCard image={card.HipHop.url}/>
    )
  })
  return (
<div className="App">
  {maincard}
</div>
```

)
}

and here is MainCard

```
function MainCard(props){
return(
    <div className="mainCard">
        <img src={props.image} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a component with a prop called `image`:

```
<MainCard image={card.HipHop[0].url}/>
```

Inside that component, you should reference it as `image`:

```
function MainCard(props){
    return(
        <div className="mainCard">
            <img src={props.image} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

As @James points out, you would have to reference your url like `card.HipHop[0].url` because `HipHop` is an array.

Comment: I have amended my code so that in the related component I have {props.image}, the issue persists however.

Comment: The problem actually starts with your data, you are calling `map` on what is effectively an object (which will fail).

Comment: @James I have commented that out and instead did this within my code 
```<div className="App">
      
      <MainCard image={Data.HipHop.url} />
    </div>``` 
Let to no avail.

Comment: @bit.con that's still not going to work because each named key's value is a list, so would need to be `Data.Hiphop[0].url`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping the data in a json file, I would instead use a js file like this.

```
export default data = [
    {
        id:1,
        url:process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/MainCardImages.hiphopMainCard.png",
        description:"HipHopCard",
        title:"Hip Hop"
    },
    {
        id:2,
        url:process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/MainCardImages.houseMainCard.png",
        description:"House Card",
        title:"House"
    }
]
```

Also I used `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` instead of `../public` because in my projects I always get some sort of error if I do it that way.

Comment: Moving the data from a JSON file to a JS file doesn't address the problem.

Comment: Answer doesnt addess the issue but just an unrelated suggestion